# XSLT Removing my closing image tags

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm having a bit off an issue with my XSLT.

I'm using:

```
<img src="{@url}" alt="{@alt}" title="{@title}" />
```

However in my output I am getting :

```
<img src="dldldl" alt="kdkdkdkd" title="dkdkdk">
```

The closing tag has now been removed. I've looked around and seen some issues like this but most are resolved by changing to  `<xsl:output method="html"` which I already have.

This is the head of my XSLT file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `method="xml"`?

Comment: Yep no joy its very frustrating

Comment: How are you applying the XSLT, and how are you inspecting the output?

Comment: Im inspecting the output in firebug and in page source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by changing too tomcat, when running localy our devs where running the app with jetty which seems to run xsl differently.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have it the wrong way around. With method="xml" the element will be closed (`<img/>`) - with HTML it won't (`<img>`)